# Ajax with servlet - how can i manage to make doGet?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I have a function in Javascript which is checking my servlet:

```
function validate() {
var idField = document.getElementById("name1");
var data = "name1=" + encodeURIComponent(idField.value);
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var url = "Validator"
req.open("POST", url, true);        
req.onreadystatechange = inserter
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   req.send(data);
}

function inserter() {
if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        var msg1 = req.responseText
    if (msg1 == "") {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "<div style=\"color:red\">Wadliwa nazwa</div>";
        document.getElementById("org").value = ''
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("org").value = msg1
    }
}
```

I have found out that:
Instruction

> req.onreadystatechanged = inserter

sets the function responsible for handling server response.

Inserter function which dynamically changes the content of a page will be invoked asynchronously in case the server response arrives.

On my servlet I am getting the parameter from my website:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("name1"));
    if(!request.getParameter("name1").equals("")) {
        serviceConnection(request, response);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to do the same thing, but as the doGet, I can't do it at all...:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("name2"));
    if(!request.getParameter("name2").equals("")) {
        serviceConnection(request, response);
    }
}
```

I was trying to change in the code of the ajax into:

```
var url = "Validator/?" + data2;
req.open("GET", url, true);        
req.onreadystatechange = inserter2;
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem?
Shall I do something other than

> req.onreadystatechanged = inserter
>   to have a doGet function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code.. I corrected it cose you had misssing closing brackets, it should work now ..

```
function validate() {
    var idField = document.getElementById("name1");
    var data = "name1=" + encodeURIComponent(idField.value);
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "Validator"
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = inserter
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send(data);
}


function inserter() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            var msg1 = req.responseText
            if (msg1 == "") {
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "<div style=\"color:red\">Wadliwa nazwa</div>";
                document.getElementById("org").value = '';
            } else {
                document.getElementById("org").value = msg1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Now it works! :) I have another question regarding this task - I try to get the parameter just like here request.getParameter("name") (in doGet function()), but the function shows only null variable (if I am using them as System.out.println). How can I solve this problem/

Comment: glad it helped,, you should post another question so I'll have a look ok?